# I need to be able to hide the place order button in Magento checkout if time x is reached

Tags: javascript, magento, checkout

I need to be able to hide the “Place Order” button if a deadline is reached during the checkout phase. In this store customers are picking routes for their orders and then they pick up their orders from the route.

When customer picks a route a cookie with a deadline time is set, i need to compare this cookie to current time in real-time during checkout progress to make sure that customers cant place orders to a route that has been closed.

I have the time compare working in PHP but it only gets the current time on page load, so if someone spends too much time in the checkout it might be a problem.  I have tried ajax scripts and placed them inside the `button.phtml` but for some reason they dont seem to work. I am sure this is something related to magento’s theme/file structure that i am not getting.

Comment: On the client side you should be able to do this with javascript.

Comment: Its looking pretty simple so far. I will post my implementation once its finished.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution so far. Its very straightforward but my problem now is that i cant figure out how to get the current time from the server as javascript is client side it uses user's settings for clock. Its surprisingly difficult to do this one simple thing. I think i can figure it out soon enough.

This code resides in `button.phtml`

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('deadline_reached').style.visibility = 'hidden';  

  function validateDeadline() {

   <?php 

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Helsinki');
    $deadlineTimeHuman=$_COOKIE["deadlineDate"];
    $deadlineTimeUnixTimestamp = strtotime($deadlineTimeHuman);
     ?>

  // Current date 
  var timeNowCompare = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) //Current date is changed to unix timestamp without milliseconds os it matches with php's timestamp format.

  //Cookie's deadline time which has been changed to timestamp is loaded into variable.
  var deadlineDate = "<?php echo $deadlineTimeUnixTimestamp ?>";

  if (timeNowCompare < deadlineDate) // What happens when we are in schedule.
  { 
  alert("Now < Deadline Order can be placed \n"+"n:"+ timeNowCompare +"\nd:"+deadlineDate); // This is for debugging
  }
  else if (timeNowCompare > deadlineDate) // What happens when current time is higher than deadline.
  { 
  alert("Now > Deadline Order cant be placed \n"+"n:"+ timeNowCompare +"\nd:"+deadlineDate); // This is for debugging
  document.getElementById('place_order_btn').style.visibility = 'hidden';  
  document.getElementById('deadline_reached').style.visibility = 'visible'; 

  }     
}  

window.setInterval(function(){
  validateDeadline();
 }, 10000);
</script>
```